# Running 32 bit app on Windows 7 with dependent DLLs

Tags: windows, qt, dll, 64-bit, runtime.exec

I have a simple 32 bit app running. It uses Qt and other libraries. Having figured out manifests, I have a folder containing the app , manifests and dependent DLLs. Running this on the target machine under Windows 7 64 bit straight from a USB stick works. Copying this to a folder on the `D:\` drive and it works.

Copying this to a folder under `Program files (x86)` and I get :

> R6034. An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly.

I have a manifest for my executable. I also have the manifest for the `msvc*.dll`'s in the folder as suggested elsewhere in this forum. So, why does this work everywhere except in the place it's supposed to be?

Comment: Have you considered using the static runtime instead of the DLL?

Comment: Ben. It's VC2008. Harry, yes I have but I was hoping not to go there. It seems to me there's something about Windows 7 64 bit I don't understand. The same apps  built as 32 bit work perfectly.

Comment: I assume it works if you put it in Program Files on a 32-bit machine?  Which version of Visual Studio and which language?

Comment: Just to make sure, use Process Monitor to confirm that your copy of the MSVC DLL is being loaded.

Comment: Harry, it's C++ with Qt built under VS2008. I'll try your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) will help here - run it on your .exe when it's in a working state and when it's not and compare the locations of the C runtime library your app is attempting to use (I believe it should be **msvcrt.dll** if you're in release, **msvcrtd.dll** if you're not) and you'll hopefully be able to spot a difference.

I'm not certain where you could go from there - perhaps deploy the correct version of the dll into the same folder as your .exe?

Comment: sjwarner - thanks. I have used dependency walker a lot and it doesn't show any problems apart from the usual missing ieshims.sll which I ignore. All my dlls , including the runtime dlls are deployed in the same folder as the .exe.